# Перепределение конструктора в подклассе

Tags: наследование, классы, java, конструктор

Здравствуйте! Проблема заключается вот в чем:
у меня имеется родительский класс Vehicle и в нем у меня есть такой конструктор:

```
class Vehicle{
public Vehicle(double petrol, double vol){
    this.setPetrolAmount(petrol);
    this.setTankVolume(vol);
}
public void setPetrolAmount(double petrolAmount) {this.petrolAmount = petrolAmount; }
public void setTankVolume(double tankVolume) {  this.tankVolume = tankVolume;}
...
}
```

Затем у меня есть подкласс Bus, где я сделал такой конструктор:

```
class Bus extends Vehicle{

public Bus( int people, int max_people, double petrol, double max_petrol){
    super(petrol, max_petrol);
    this.people = people;
    this.max_people = max_people;
}
...
    int people;
    int max_people;
}
```

Так вот, в чем трабл: наследование происходит, но переменные people и max-people преобразуются в double, а мне нужно, чтобы они были int. Грубо говоря, мне нужно засунуть строчку "super(petrol, max-petrol);" под "this.max-people = max-people;" и все было бы как нужно, но вылетает ошибка. Вопрос, может, и бредовый, но прошу помощи.

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Как аргументы конструктора Bus() вдруг преобразуются в double? Вызов конструктора суперкласса или другого конструктора данного класса может располагаться только в начале тела конструктора.

Comment: >наследование происходит, но переменные people и max-people преобразуются в double,

с чего вы это взяли?

Comment: @a_gura , (int, int, double, double) , т.е. последние как бы становятся дабл (хотя сами обьявлены как инт). Причем первые дабл, но тем не менее не против int при обьявлении параметров.

Comment: @DreamChild , при "System.out.println( "People = " + v.getPeopleCount() );" выводит "People = 32.0" (например), а не "People = 32"

Comment: @111xbot111 понятнее не стало. Параметры конструктора класса Bus petrol и max_petrol имеют тип double, а не int. Они же передаются как параметры в констурктор класса Vehicle, который также ожидает параметры типа double. Не вижу никаких противоречий и int'ов.

Comment: >при "System.out.println( "People = " + v.getPeopleCount() );" выводит "People = 32.0" 

ну так вы покажите свой код. Откуда нам знать, что у вас происходит в методе getPeopleCount и что именно он возвращает? 

Впрочем, дайте угадаю, ваш getPeopleCount имеет следующий вид: 

    public double getPeopleCount() { return  people; }

отчего вы выводите int, который неявно преобразуется к double

Comment: @111xbot111 гадание по намерениям. А где же код метода getPeopleCount и собственно объявление переменных people и max_people? И вообще этот комментарий делает бессмысленным весь ваш вопрос.

Comment: @DreamChild, ну я и дурак. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

цитата из вашего кода:

```
public double getPeopleCount() {
    return people;
}
```

у вас метод getPeopleCount имеет возвращаемый тип double, тогда как вы возвращаете int (people), отчего int кастуется к double. Внимательнее делайте копипаст

Answer (score -1):

Я, может, глупость скажу, но почему бы не создать конструктор по умолчанию, без параметров, а потом методами типа setPetrolAmount() выставить значения всех полей? И лучше на всякий случай переименовать параметры, чтобы не совпадали с именами полей.

Comment: Я пробовал делать так (ну или типа такого). Тут уже вылетает другая ошибка:Implicit super constructor Vehicle() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke  another constructor. Не хочет почему-то без super() в обще конструктор создавать.

Comment: Плохой дизайн. Автор конечно не указывает своего стремления к immutabilty, но тем не менее лучше использовать создание через конструктор или builder, чтобы созданный объект не мог быть изменен клиентским кодом.

Comment: @111xbot111, забавно, но у меня всё нормально работает. Взял только указанные куски кода, вызвал конструктор Bus, вывел данные полей - все должных типов: people и max_people - int, petrolAmount, tankVolume - double. Вы уверены, что проблема именно в конструкторе, а не где-то ещё?

Comment: @Yuri_Prime , к сожалению, с текущими познаниями в джава я не уверен ни в чём. Но если у Вас правильно (т.е. у Вас при "System.out.println( "People = " + v.getPeopleCount() );" выводит "People = 32.0" (например), а не "People = 32", так?), то должно быть правильно и у меня. Но я все-таки думаю, что проблема где-то в конструкторах. В крайнем случае, выкину весь код, может быть( скорее, наверняка), кто-то углядит больше, чем я.

Comment: @111xbot111, вот весь код посмотреть было бы очень даже неплохо

Comment: @111xbot111, всё именно так, как сказал DreamChild. public double getPeopleCount() и public double getMaxPeopleCount() надо сменить на public int

Comment: @111xbot111 Ох! Ваш метод getPeopleCount() возвращает double, потому что вы его так объявили.